# How to use GetPixel() to check different positions

Tags: c++, winapi, getpixel

I have a program that HAS to use GetPixel, but in different positions, after reading one value and evaluating it, it has to change the x,y positions and re-evaluate the values of the other function.
I have the current code:

```
while (true) {
        HDC hDC;
        hDC = GetDC(NULL);
       int cx = 793;
       int cy = 866;
COLORREF color = GetPixel(hDC, cx, cy); //Use x=793 y=866
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
        RGBTRIPLE rgb;
        int red = GetRValue(color);
        int green = GetGValue(color);
        int blue = GetBValue(color);
        std::thread t1 (verde, red, green, blue); 
        t1.join();
        std::thread t2(amarelo, red, green, blue);//But then here I would like it to read
       //from let's say x=803 y=796
        t2.join();
 }
```

The problem is GetPixel should use X=793 AND Y=866 for the `verde` function and then use x=803 y=796 for the `amarelo` function

Comment: Then just do so. Call `GetPixel()` again with the new values. Does that not work?

Comment: wouldn't I have to declare another int red and int green... ? like int reda just to pass the new value? Wouldn't that create a unecessary memory usage?

Comment: Call "GetPixel" in thread functions instead of outside, I mean in functions "verde" and "amarelo". with your different x,y values.

Comment: @MatheusSouza: no, just use the variables you already have.  You can assign new values to them.

Comment: The program is only getting to calling verde function, amarelo is not running at all. I added a breakpoint into verde function and it's getting crazy numbers while debbuging like the green color is   g -858993460 int

Comment: @PAVANCHANDAKA: If you read and comprehended the code, you cannot possibly arrive at the conclusion to keep using threads. Those threads are simply overly wasteful, serialized function calls.

Comment: Do you understand how variables work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that you can call `GetPixel()` multiple times with different coordinates.

Also, there is no need to call `GetDC(0)` on each loop iteration. You should call it one time before entering the loop.

Try this:

```
COLORREF color;
int red, green, blue;

HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
while (some_condition_is_true) { // don't write infinite loops!
    color = GetPixel(hDC, 793, 866);
    red = GetRValue(color);
    green = GetGValue(color);
    blue = GetBValue(color);
    std::thread t1(verde, red, green, blue); 
    t1.join();

    color = GetPixel(hDC, 803, 796);
    red = GetRValue(color);
    green = GetGValue(color);
    blue = GetBValue(color);
    std::thread t2(amarelo, red, green, blue);
    t2.join();
}
ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
```

However, that being said, your threads are wasted overhead.  Your loop is blocked waiting for the first thread to complete before starting the second thread, and is blocked waiting on the second thread to complete before going to the next loop iteration.  You are running your code in a serialized manner, defeating the purpose of using threads, so you may as well just remove the threads altogether and call the functions directly:

```
COLORREF color;
int red, green, blue;

HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
while (some_condition_is_true) {
    color = GetPixel(hDC, 793, 866);
    red = GetRValue(color);
    green = GetGValue(color);
    blue = GetBValue(color);
    verde(red, green, blue);

    color = GetPixel(hDC, 803, 796);
    red = GetRValue(color);
    green = GetGValue(color);
    blue = GetBValue(color);
    amarelo(red, green, blue);
}
ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
```

If you want to use threads to process multiple pixels in parallel, it should look more like this:

```
COLORREF color;
int red, green, blue;

HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
while (some_condition_is_true) {
    color = GetPixel(hDC, 793, 866);
    red = GetRValue(color);
    green = GetGValue(color);
    blue = GetBValue(color);
    std::thread t1(verde, red, green, blue); 

    color = GetPixel(hDC, 803, 796);
    red = GetRValue(color);
    green = GetGValue(color);
    blue = GetBValue(color);
    std::thread t2(amarelo, red, green, blue);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
```

Or even like this:

```
void verde(HDC hDC, int x, int y)
{
    COLORREF color;
    int red, green, blue;

    while (some_condition_is_true) {
        color = GetPixel(hDC, x, y);
        red = GetRValue(color);
        green = GetGValue(color);
        blue = GetBValue(color);
        //...
    }
} 

void amarelo(HDC hDC, int x, int, y)
{
    COLORREF color;
    int red, green, blue;

    while (some_condition_is_true) {
        color = GetPixel(hDC, x, y);
        red = GetRValue(color);
        green = GetGValue(color);
        blue = GetBValue(color);
        //...
    }
}
```

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);

std::thread t1(verde, hDC, 793, 866);
std::thread t2(amarelo, hDC, 803, 796);

t1.join();
t2.join();

ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
```